# Clear multiple textboxes Jquery

Tags: jquery

i have multiple textboxes with the sameID on a page that are generated programatically. This clears the first textbox.

```
$('#commentText').val('');
```

But will not clear other text boxes with the same ID. How can i make jquery clear all textboxes with the ID commentText.

Alternatively, i can give these text boxes unique names is there a way to specify which textbox to clear by a property other than the ID?

Thanks

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with same ID. IDs must be unique in HTML

Comment: You can't have multiple items with the same ID in valid HTML - give them all a class and use that instead

Comment: Why are you using same Id on different places ? It's normal that it can't work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`id`** must be unique.  Instead use **`class`**

```
$('.commentText').val('');
```

FYI: `.` is used for class  selector

Answer (score 1):

Don't use same ID for multiple textboxes. Use class instead.

Then:

```
$('.commentText').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<html>
 <head>
   <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    function myFun(){
$('.test').val('');
    }
   </script>

  </head>
 <body>

   <input type="text" class="test" value="xxxxxxxxxx" ><br>
   <input type="text" class="test" value="xxxxxxxxxx"><br>
   <input type="text" class="test" value="xxxxxxxxxx"><br>
   <input type="text" class="test" value="xxxxxxxxxx"><br>
   <input type="text" class="test" value="xxxxxxxxxx"><br>
   <input type="text" class="test" value="xxxxxxxxxx"><br>
   <input type="text" class="test" value="xxxxxxxxxx"><br>

   <input type="button" onclick="myFun()" value="clear_All">
</body>
```